# Мобильный сайт, редирект, выдача гугла

Tags: php, html, seo, google-search

Разрабатываю мобильную версию сайта магазина и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть сайт site.com и его мобильная версия на другом домене m.site.com(физически точная копия сайта в другом каталоге с другими соответственно шаблонами html разметки). Перенаправление с основной версии на мобильную выполнен на php. На мобильной версии просто ссылка на полную.
Теперь собственно проблема, при поиске с обычного десктопного браузера, ссылки в гугл ведут соответственно на обычную версию (http://site.com/catalog/488). А при поиске с мобильного по тому же гуглу выдают ссылки вида http://**m**.site.com/catalog/488 (что в общем логично). Так вот задача стоит такая - сделать так, что бы при поиске со смартфона в результатах отображалась именно ссылка на основной сайт.
Как пример могу привести такой запрос с Android смартфона в гугл. Ввожу в поиск "baby clothes"
Один из результатов сайт "www.gymboree.com" именно так отображается ссылка. Ну и при переходе происходит редирект на мобильную версию.
При этом перейти на обычную версию с мобильного тоже можно. Т.е. редирект выполнен не при помощи .htaccess определения HTTP_USER_AGENT.
Теперь если кратко, **как добиться что бы при выдаче результатов с мобильного гугла отображалась ссылка на основной сайт а не на мобильную версию?**

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [robots.txt](http://robotstxt.org.ru/), с зеркалами сайта рекомендуется использовать директиву «Host».

Comment: В этом есть смысл, почитал по подробнее, поставил, ждем результатов, когда гугл переидексирует. Если прокатит, отмечу правильным.

Comment: Пока что-то не работает. Вроде как гугл переиндексировал страницы, но буква m не ушла.
Напомню проблему, при поиске с мобильного в результатах гугла выдает ссылку на мобильную версию m.site.com, а нужно что бы в мобильном поиске было просто site.com
В robots.txt в мобильной версии директива Host указана www.site.com, как и в robots основного сайта.

Comment: Проблема еще актуальна ?
Если да то попробуйте в htaccess прописать при помощи подуля mod_rewrite redirect (301) на нужный вам домен. http://sb-money.ru/article.php?a=75